# panda add several new columns based on values from other columns at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to add several new columns based on values from other columns **at the same time**? I only found examples to add a row one at a time.

I am able to add 3 new columns but this does not seem efficient since it has to go through all the rows 3 times.
Is there a way to traverse the DF once?

```
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal
d = [
    {'A': 2, 'B': Decimal('628.00')},
    {'A': 1, 'B': Decimal('383.00')},
    {'A': 3, 'B': Decimal('651.00')},
    {'A': 2, 'B': Decimal('575.00')},
    {'A': 4, 'B': Decimal('1114.00')},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

In : df
Out:
   A        B
0  2   628.00
1  1   383.00
2  3   651.00
3  2   575.00
4  4  1114.00

# How to do those in one operation to avoid traversing the DF 3 times
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['B']-1000, axis=1)
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['B']*row['B'], axis=1)
df['E'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['B']/2, axis=1)

In : df
Out:
   A        B        C             D       E
0  2   628.00  -372.00   394384.0000  314.00
1  1   383.00  -617.00   146689.0000  191.50
2  3   651.00  -349.00   423801.0000  325.50
3  2   575.00  -425.00   330625.0000  287.50
4  4  1114.00   114.00  1240996.0000  557.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a lambda function.  Simple vectorized implementation is both faster and easier to read.

```
df['C'] = df['B'] - 1000
df['D'] = df['B'] ** 2
df['E'] = df['B'] / 2

>>> df
   A        B        C             D       E
0  2   628.00  -372.00   394384.0000  314.00
1  1   383.00  -617.00   146689.0000  191.50
2  3   651.00  -349.00   423801.0000  325.50
3  2   575.00  -425.00   330625.0000  287.50
4  4  1114.00   114.00  1240996.0000  557.00
```

Let's time it on a dataframe with one million rows:

```
df = pd.concat([df for _ in range(200000)], ignore_index=True)
>>> df.shape
(1000000, 2)

>>> %%timeit -n 3
    df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['B'] - 1000, axis=1)
    df['D'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['B'] * row['B'], axis=1)
    df['E'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['B'] / 2, axis=1)
3 loops, best of 3: 1min 20s per loop

>>> %%timeit -n 3
    df['C'] = df['B'] - 1000
    df['D'] = df['B'] ** 2
    df['E'] = df['B'] / 2
3 loops, best of 3: 49.7 s per loop
```

The speed is **significantly faster** if you did away with the Decimal type and used a float instead:

```
d = [
    {'A': 2, 'B': 628.00},
    {'A': 1, 'B': 383.00},
    {'A': 3, 'B': 651.00},
    {'A': 2, 'B': 575.00},
    {'A': 4, 'B': 1114.00}]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = pd.concat([df for _ in range(200000)], ignore_index=True)

>>> %%timeit -n 3
    df['C'] = df['B'] - 1000
    df['D'] = df['B'] ** 2
    df['E'] = df['B'] / 2
3 loops, best of 3: 33.1 ms per loop

>>> df.shape
(1000000, 5)
```

Comment: Whether the speed of this operation is important is unknown -- it probably isn't at all. It's certainly the nice, normal, readable thing to use serieswise operations rather than apply in these sorts of cases, though.

Comment: @MikeGraham Given the OP's comment in the second paragraph about efficiency, I interpret that as efficiency for speed.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. If I well understand how pandas works, it will have to go through the whole DF each time for each line / new column we add correct? So in this case it will loop 3 times through the whole DF because we add 3 columns. If I want to add more columns, is there a way to improve this since there is no point going through the whole DF each time. Is it possible to calculate all the new columns on each row at the same time and therefore loop through the DF just once? Maybe it isn't faster anyway? I don't know well pandas yet. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the difference with using float is impressive. Would `df['B'] = df['B'].astype(numpy.float64)` be the correct way of casting a column of Decimal objects? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can cast as `df['B'].astype('float')` or  `df['B'].astype(np.float)`, or  `df['B'].astype(np.float32)`

Comment: Regarding your other comment, you appear to be hung up about some inefficiency that just is not there.  It is very efficient.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was just wondering the proper way to use pandas as I'm new to it. I thought that if I have to add 30 columns on a 1,000,000 rows dataframe then I should rather find a way to go through the 1,000,000 rows once and not 30 times.